# How to split one list item into two (log files)

Tags: python, list, parsing, split, logfile

What I have now
`['DRR2018-05-24', '12:14:12.054\n']`

What I would to have
`['DRR', '2018-05-24', '12:14:12.054\n']`

Working with log files and in other log files I have element like this `'DRR'` And for navigate or sorted want to split one list item and use this abbreviation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can do it using re(Regular Expressions Library)*

```
arr=['DRR2018-05-24','12:14:12.054\n']
new_arr=[]
for i in arr:
  k=re.split('[DRR]',i)
  new_arr=new_arr+k
```

Comment: I think, here we need to use `append` for correctly work

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try:

```
lst = ['DRR2018-05-24', '12:14:12.054\n']
new_lst = [j for i in lst for j in i.partition('DRR') if j!= '']
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
['DRR', '2018-05-24', '12:14:12.054\n']
```